# Proving g(x) is integrable, knowing f(x,y) is integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am a self learner on measure theory and am following the notation on Bartle, but when I was looking at the following problem I was not able to draw out a convincing approach and would like to know if somebody may have an idea as to what should be done. I know the other implication isn't true. What I was thinking on doing was trying to prove that if there were to exist a function f(x,y) which is not lebesgue integrable over such interval, then it must be that g is not lebesgue integrable over [0,1]. I didn't get anywhere with this and have thought about it some time, but haven't connected the pieces correctly.
I am real grateful for any ideas given.

Let $g:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ be a Lebesgue measurable function such that the function $f(x,y)=2g(x)-3g(y)$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[0,1]$ x $[0,1]$. Prove that g is Lebesgue integrable over $[0,1]$.

Comment: You know $f$ is integral. What happens if you try to integrate $f(x,y)$ as given with respect to the product measure (\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y) ?(Fubini's theorem is needed for this)

Comment: The harder part is showing that $g$ is Lebesgue measurable. If $f$ were merely Borel measurable, then for any fixed $y$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ would be Borel measurable, but Lebesgue measurability can be more complicated. What is true, however, is that if $f$ is Lebesgue measurable then for a.e. $y$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is Lebesgue measurable (one can prove this with yet another Fubini-Tonelli application).

Comment: I just saw that the poster assumes that $g$ is Lebesgue measurable. Still, even if we only assume that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, we can get our hands on $g$ being Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} \int_0^{1} |2g(x)-3g(y)| \, dx \, dy<\infty$. This implies, by Fubini/Tonelli's Theorem that $ \int_0^{1} |2g(x)-3g(y)| \, dx <\infty$ for almost all $y$. Just fix one such $y$ and note that $ \int_0^{1} |2g(x)| \, dx \leq  \int_0^{1} |2g(x)-3g(y)| \, dx +3|g(y)|$ [Lebesgue measurability of $g$ is not a problem. For each fixed $y$, $x\to f(x,y)$ is Lebesgue measurable].

Comment: That inequality is my new best friend. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is integrable, Fubini's theorem implies that the integral over $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ of $f$ exists and can be computed iteratively via
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dxdy &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 2g(x)-3g(y) dxdy \\
&= \int_0^1\left( \int_0^1 2g(x)dx-3g(y)\right)dy \\
&= 2\int_0^1 g(x)dx - 3\int_0^1 g(y)dy \\
&= -\int_0^1 g(x)dx.
\end{align*}
Hence if $g$ were not integrable, then this last expression would be undefined, and so $f$ would also not be integrable.

Comment: Application of Fubini's Theorem  is  not justified. You need either an intergrable function or a non-negative function of two variable to apply the theorem.